# A connection between them

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a term that establishes connection between a person and a certain object. As an example, if one of my friends(not with me now) used to have one particular chocolate bar, say X, and now I get reminded of him whenever I see th bar X or hear of X, then what could that connection be called?

likewise, if some particular event or object has the same reminiscence or connection, what can such a relation or situation be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that will be a ***[reminder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reminder)***:

> a person or thing that reminds, or causes one to remember.

You see a chocolate bar, it reminds you of your friend - this bar serves as a reminder for you.

Other possible words: ***memento***, ***souvenir***, ***remembrancer*** - but these are usually tied to a unique object someone has, not a general brand like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The event / situation / object is a *memory trigger*.

[This article](http://marvwalker.com/trigger.htm) discusses various types. It is rather whimsical. Though I don't think any of the writer's horses were actually called Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

**Ecphorize** or **Ecphore** [To evoke or revive (an emotion, a memory, or the like) by means of a stimulus. So ecphoric (ɛkˈfɒrɪk) a., pertaining to or characterized by ecphory; whence ecˈphorically adv. Also ecphorize (ˈɛkfəraɪz) v.; whence ˈecphorizable a.; ecphory (ˈɛkfərɪ) [ad. G. ekphorie (R. Semon ibid. 25)], the evocation of a disposition from a latent to a manifest state.](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/201279/ecphore)

> There is a word, once applied to an herb, now obsolete, that some
>   would like restored to the language: anacampserote: Gr. ana, again,
>   -f- campserota from camptein, to bend, + eros, erot—, love (whence also Eng. erotic) : that which brings back departed love.

-Dictionary of word origins, . Shipley, Joseph T. (Joseph Twadell), 1893-1988

Comment: This sounds like the reminder is making you violently ill!

Answer (score 0):

A memory that is triggered by a sense. This reminds me of Proust's madeleine where Proust, on drinking tea and eating a madeleine cake soaked in the tea, found his thoughts transported back to his childhood. He called it involuntary memory.

I have also heard it referred to as autobiographical memory, flashback, a memory hook, a Proustian recall/effect/phenomenon. The chocolate bar itself could be a mnemonic or a redolent.